# After 'takePicture' call, 'onPictureTaken' response is dependent on location in app...why?

Tags: java, android, callback, android-camera

I'm trying to build an app which will periodically call the Camera to take a picture and save it.
My problem is that unless I put the 'takePictuce' call in the 'onCreate' the response to 'takePicture' (onPictureTaken) is never called.

I've broken down the app as simply as possible to illustrate.

if a class to handle the camera is partially defined as:

```
public class CameraHandler {
    private Camera mCamera;

    public CameraHandler(){
        mCamera = Camera.open();
        mCamera.setPreviewTexture(new SurfaceTexture(10));

        mCamera.startPreview();
        mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
    }

    Camera.PictureCallback mPicture = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();
            if (pictureFile == null) {
                return;
            }
            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            } catch (IOException e) {            }
        }
    };
```

Then when I put the following code into MainActivity.java, 'onPictureTaken' IS called when CameraHandler is instantiated.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    CameraHandler cameraHandler = new CameraHandler();
}
```

However, putting the call to instantiate CameraHandler in a click event in the MainActivity.java will NOT call 'onPictureTaken' in response to the takePicture call.

```
(This snippet is located in MainACtivity.java)
  public void onClickListener(View view){
        CameraHandler cameraHandler = new CameraHandler();
}
```

So why is this occurring, and how can I get the call to take a picture in the class where it belongs and not in the 'main' of the program?

All help welcome

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out how to set the phone to take timed pics without any screen display. 
There were 2 main issues I struggled with. First, I wanted to take the pics without displaying to screen. Along those lines, I found an example where they used :
    mCamera.setPreviewTexture(new SurfaceTexture(10)); 
and nothing showed on the screen when using this preview method. It appears that some sort of preview is required. Another method was to set the preview to 1 pixel. This method had examples online which appeared to work as well, but I did not try it.

The second and bigger problem had to do with 'onPictureTaken' method. This method processes your picture after the 'takePicture' call.
It seemed that no matter what looping method I used, or where in the code the call to 'takePicture' was located, all of the 'onPictureTaken' methods were queued up and called one after another once the parent of the 'takePicture' caller ended.

Although the picture data processed by onPictureTaken were in a proper time sequence, I could see that having several hundred pics stored and waiting to process could cause problems, and a method needed to be found where on pic was processed and stored before the next pic was taken.

Along those lines, I stumbled upon the AlarmManager and coupled that with the BroadcastReceiver and Future classes to solve the problem.

What I've done is set the alarmManger to go off at a set time or time frequency. The BroadcaseReceiver captures this call & in turn calls a method which creates
a thread where a 'Future' object makes the call to take a picture.

'Future' object is nice, because it will wait for the physical camera to take the picture (takePicture) and then process it (onPictureTaken). This all occurs in one thread, then terminates. So no queuing of pics to process and each picture sequence is handled separately.

Code is contained below. Note that some of the default 'Overrides' have been left out to save space. Also, the visible screen was basically a button which captured the click event...very basic.
MainActivity.java:
    package myTest.com.test;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
CameraHandler cameraHandler;
public BroadcastReceiver br;
public PendingIntent pi;
public AlarmManager am;

final static private long LOOPTIME = 20000;
private static final ExecutorService threadpool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setup();
}

private void setup() {
    try{
        cameraHandler = new CameraHandler();
        br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i) {
                //Toast.makeText(c, "Taking a pic!",   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                TryAThread();
            }
        };
        registerReceiver(br, new IntentFilter("com.timedActivity.activity") );
        pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent("com.timedActivity.activity"), 0);
        am = (AlarmManager)(this.getSystemService( Context.ALARM_SERVICE ));
    }
    catch (Exception e){        }
}

private void TryAThread()  {
    try{
        CameraCaller cameraCaller = new CameraCaller(cameraHandler);
        Future future = threadpool.submit(cameraCaller);

        while (!future.isDone()) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (Exception ex) { }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){        }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    am.cancel(pi);
    unregisterReceiver(br);
    super.onDestroy();
}

public void onClickListener(View view){
    try{
        am.setRepeating(am.ELAPSED_REALTIME,SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), LOOPTIME, pi);
    }
    catch (Exception e){        }
}
```

}

CameraCaller.java:.

```
package myTest.com.test;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

public class CameraCaller implements Callable {
private CameraHandler cameraHandler;
public CameraCaller(CameraHandler ch){
    cameraHandler = ch;
}

@Override
public Object call() throws Exception {
    cameraHandler.takeAPic();
    return true;
}
```

}

CameraHandler.java:.

```
package myTest.com.test;

import android.graphics.SurfaceTexture;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import junit.runner.Version;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class CameraHandler implements Camera.PictureCallback{
private Camera mCamera;
public  CameraHandler(){
}

  public Boolean takeAPic(){
    try{
        if (mCamera == null){
            mCamera = Camera.open();
            mCamera.enableShutterSound(false);

            try {
                mCamera.setPreviewTexture(new SurfaceTexture(10));
            }
            catch (IOException e1) {Log.e(Version.id(), e1.getMessage()); 
            }
        }
        mCamera.startPreview();
        mCamera.takePicture(null, null, this);
    }
    catch (Exception ex){        }
      return  true;
}

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();
        if (pictureFile == null) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            fos.write(data);
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        } catch (IOException e) {            }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }catch (Exception ex){}
    }

public static File getOutputMediaFile() {
    File file = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(file, "MyCameraApp");
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
            return null;
        }
    }
    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
    return mediaFile;
}
```

}